# Trouble with CSS animation in Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: css, firefox, animation, slider

I know this has probably been answered somewhere else, but I can't seem to find a solution and implement it. I have and CSS slider animation that works properly in Safari and Chrome but not in Firefox and IE. I have tried to use the vendor selectors but I am probably doing it wrong. This is my first time to code anything and I was only given a week to do it for a class. This is really the last thing I have to do. So how can I get my animation to work in IE and Firefox?

You can visit the site [here](http://thomashall.idesignclass.com).

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="captioned-gallery">
            <figure class="slider">
                <figure>
                    <img src="Images/hungarian-goulash_10-20-13_1_ca.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt="Photo of Hungarian Sausage Goulash"/>
                        <figcaption class="slider2">Hungarian Sausage Goulash</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <figure>
                    <img src="Images/G-lasagne-al-forno.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt="Photo of Lasagne al Forno"/>
                        <figcaption class="slider2">Lasagna al Forno</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <figure>
                    <img src="Images/5357829-svickova.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt="Photo of Svickova"/>
                        <figcaption class="slider2">Svickova</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <figure>
                    <img src="Images/pork shoulder.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt="Photo of Pork Shoulder with Dumplings"/>
                        <figcaption class="slider2">Pork Shoulder with Dumplings</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <figure>
                    <img src="Images/hungarian-goulash_10-20-13_1_ca.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt="Photo of Hungarian Sausage Goulash"/>
                        <figcaption class="slider2">Hungarian Sausage Goulash</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </figure>
```

And my CSS

```
div#captioned-gallery {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
}

figure {
    margin: 0;
}

figure.slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    font-size: 0;
    -webkit-animation: 20s slidy ease-in-out infinite;
    -moz-animation: 20s slidy ease-in-out infinite;
    -ms-animation: 20s slidy ease-in-out infinite;
    animation: 20s slidy ease-in-out infinite;
}

figure.slider figure 
    {
        width: 20%; 
        height: auto;
        display: inline-block;
        position: inherit;
}

figure.slider img
    { 
        width: 100%;
        height: auto; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidy {
    20% { left: 0%; }
    25% { left: -100%; }
    45% { left: -100%; }
    50% { left: -200%; }
    70% { left: -200%; }
    75% { left: -300%; }
    95% { left: -300%; }
    100% { left: -400%; }
}

@keyframes slidy {
    20% { left: 0%; }
    25% { left: -100%; }
    45% { left: -100%; }
    50% { left: -200%; }
    70% { left: -200%; }
    75% { left: -300%; }
    95% { left: -300%; }
    100% { left: -400%; }
}

@-ms-keyframes slidy {
    20% { left: 0%; }
    25% { left: -100%; }
    45% { left: -100%; }
    50% { left: -200%; }
    70% { left: -200%; }
    75% { left: -300%; }
    95% { left: -300%; }
    100% { left: -400%; }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

For firefox use `-moz-` and follow the following order. 1 more thing that animation is supported in IE 10+ versions by Microsoft. [See Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
@-moz-keyframes slidy {
    20% { left: 0%; }
    25% { left: -100%; }
    45% { left: -100%; }
    50% { left: -200%; }
    70% { left: -200%; }
    75% { left: -300%; }
    95% { left: -300%; }
    100% { left: -400%; }
}

@-ms-keyframes slidy {
    20% { left: 0%; }
    25% { left: -100%; }
    45% { left: -100%; }
    50% { left: -200%; }
    70% { left: -200%; }
    75% { left: -300%; }
    95% { left: -300%; }
    100% { left: -400%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidy {
    20% { left: 0%; }
    25% { left: -100%; }
    45% { left: -100%; }
    50% { left: -200%; }
    70% { left: -200%; }
    75% { left: -300%; }
    95% { left: -300%; }
    100% { left: -400%; }
}

@keyframes slidy {
    20% { left: 0%; }
    25% { left: -100%; }
    45% { left: -100%; }
    50% { left: -200%; }
    70% { left: -200%; }
    75% { left: -300%; }
    95% { left: -300%; }
    100% { left: -400%; }
}
```

And update your css with given below:

```
figure.slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    font-size: 0;

    -moz-animation-duration: 20s;
    -moz-animation-name: slidy;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

    -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
    -webkit-animation-name: slidy;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

    -ms-animation-duration: 20s;
    -ms-animation-name: slidy;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-direction: alternate;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: slidy;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this hasn't solved my issue. Firefox still just shows a static image rather than a slider. I was reading that it may have something to do with the positioning of the figure that prevents firefox from accepting the animation.